# Proving $\max(p) \geq \sum_d p_d^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

I want to prove
$$\max(p) \geq \sum_d p_d^2,$$
where $p$ is a simplex, satisfying $\sum_d p_d = 1$.

It looks numerically true since I run the following code in R and got true:

> library(gtools);
> D<-5;
> n<-100000;
> sum(apply(rdirichlet(n,rep(1,D)), 1, function(x){max(x)-sum(x*x)})>=0)==n

Any suggestions are appreciated. Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $p_d \leq \max(p)$ so assuming $p_d \geq 0,$ it follows that $p_d^2 \leq p_d \cdot \max(p).$

Then $$\sum_d p_d^2 \leq \sum_d p_d \cdot \max(p) = 1 \cdot \max(p)$$